# Excluding a Module from clover code coverage

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, clover

I have a maven project for which I am trying to find the code coverage using clover plugin. I want to exclude coverage for a specific module.

The module I want to exclude basically contains Util classes for tests and I don't want them to be part of the coverage report. Is there a way to exclude this entire module from coverage report instead of going through the list of packages in this module and excluding them individually?